# Проблема с типизацией string в golang

Tags: golang, типы-данных

кто читает этот вопрос. У меня возникла проблема, которое лично для меня пока не поддается здравому смыслу.

Я решаю задачу на CodeWars, условие которой выглядит следующим образом:

> Take 2 strings s1 and s2 including only letters from ato z. Return a new sorted string, the longest possible, containing distinct letters, each taken only once - coming from s1 or s2.

Казалось бы, все достаточно просто, но одна из частей моего алгоритма никак не хочет проходить, а именно:
Вот так решение у меня выходит:

```
package kata

import "strings"
import "sort"

func TwoToOne(s1 string, s2 string) string {
  var textNew string
  
  text := strings.Split(s1 + s2, " ")
  sort.Strings(text)
  text = strings.Join(text, "")
  
  for ind, elm := range text {
    if strings.Count(text, string(elm)) > 1 {
      textNew += string(elm)
      ind += strings.Count(text, string(elm))
    } else {
      textNew += string(elm)
    }
  }
```

Однако он жалуется на строку **text = strings.Join(text, "")**, выдавая ошибку:

> cannot use strings.Join(text, "") (type string) as type []string in assignment

Обратите внимание на тип переменной text: **string**
Однако, если я закомментирую эту строчку, то будет выдано следующее:

> cannot use text (type []string) as type string in argument to strings.Count

Вот вам и несостыковка: теперь он говорит, что переменная text имеет тип данных **[]string**

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как мне быть в такой ситуации?!

Comment: Где вы видите нестыковку?  И в первом, и во втором случае вам говорится, что `text` — это срез строк, а не строка.  `strings.Join` объединяет срез строк в одну.  Вы не можете использовать одно и то же имя `text` для значений разных типов.

Comment: @Ainar-G В первом же случае говорится, что подается не срез строк, а именно строка (type string). Если бы подавался срез строк (хотя это так и есть срез строк), то функция была сработала... Может я и правда что-то не понимаю... Не могли бы Вы подсказать, что и как мне лучше сделать?

Comment: Прочитайте первое сообщение внимательнее.  Говорится, что строкой является результат `strings.Join(text, "")`, который вы пытаетесь присвоить переменной `text`, которая **уже** имеет тип `[]string`.

Comment: @Ainar-G Ох, я Вас понял. Достаточно глупо с моей стороны вышло. Но как я могу обойти это и решить задачу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что же касается оригинальной задачи, это похоже на классику
про перевод из буковок в циферки и назад. Занятие
довольно бессмысленное в многоязычном тексте,
ну да ладно. Выполняется как-то так:

```golang
func f(x string, y string) (z string) {
    var letters ['z' - 'a' + 1]bool

    for _, r := range x {
        letters[r-'a'] = true
    }

    for _, r := range y {
        letters[r-'a'] = true
    }

    var zr []rune
    for i := range letters {
        if letters[i] {
            zr = append(zr, rune(i)+'a')
        }
    }

    return string(zr)
}
```

Можно выпендриться и использовать битмап вместо массива булей,
но <del>мне лень</del> это задание оставлено вам в качестве домашнего
задания по побитовым операциям :-) .

Answer (score 0):

Ответ заключался в том, что невозможно переприсваиваивать значения для одной переменной, когда речь идет о строковых типах данных.

Под капотом изменения строки происходит именно **создание** новой строки, потому ее необходимо присваивать новой переменной!